# How to create a bash function from within a .envrc?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, function

I want to use [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/) to automatically define a bash function when I switch to a particular directory. Here is the function definition.

```
seqchart () {
    # Create a sequence diagram creation shorthand
    f=$1
    target_f=${f%.*}.svg
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        diagrams sequence $f ${target_f}
        open -a firefox ${target_f}
    else
        echo "$0: No file specified"
    fi
}
```

I put the above code in the `.envrc`.

When I `cd` to the folder, I can see

```
$ cd sequence_diagrams/
direnv: loading .envrc
```

But the bash function is not created.

How can I make it happen while keeping everything in a single `.envrc`?

Comment: I normally just add a directory's `bin/` to the `$PATH` with direnv and just put my scripts there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://direnv.net/#faq), emphasis mine:

> 3. direnv is not loading the `.envrc` into the current shell. It’s creating a new bash sub-process to load the stdlib, direnvrc and
>      `.envrc`, and only exports the environment diff back to the original
>      shell. This allows direnv to record the environment changes accurately
>      and also work with all sorts of shells. It also means that aliases and
>      **functions are not exportable right now.**

Exporting the function using `export -f seqchart` might not work either, since I think bash doesn't provide a way to set environment variables of the same form as exported functions (`BASH_FUNC_foo%%`), and even if it did, I think it only reads those at startup.

Comment: No wonder even if I use `source ./function_def.sh` it also does not work. Thx.